# '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'DataFrame' when converting list of dictionaries to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a JSON file like this :

```
{
  "project_name": "Lawns & Beyond",
  "flats": [
    {
      "config": "1BHK",
      "carpet_area": "331 sq.ft",
      "carpet_rate": "25000",
      "cost": "8275000",
      "units": "303"
    },
    {
      "config": "1BHK",
      "carpet_area": "361 sq.ft",
      "carpet_rate": "25000",
      "cost": "9025000",
      "units": "300"
    },
    {
      "config": "2BHK",
      "carpet_area": "455 sq.ft",
      "carpet_rate": "25000",
      "cost": "11375000",
      "units": "715"
    },
    {
      "config": "3BHK",
      "carpet_area": "592 sq.ft",
      "carpet_rate": "25000",
      "cost": "14800000",
      "units": "165"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to save the project_name in one variable and create a pandas dataframe out of the flats.

Like this:

```
import json

d = open('sample_data/input_details.json', 'r')
details = json.load(d)

project_name = details['project_name']

unit_config = []

for i in details['flats']:
    unit_config.append(i)

unit_config = pd.DataFrame(unit_config)
```

However, I get this error

**AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'DataFrame'**

Comment: This runs as expected if adding `import pandas as pd` to the top of the provided script for me.

Comment: So it does for me as well. Was working with hydrogen on atom and saw it tick next to that import and naturally assumed that the library was already loaded. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can replace

```
unit_config = []
for i in details['flats']:
    unit_config.append(i)
unit_config = pd.DataFrame(unit_config)
```

with

```
unit_config = pd.DataFrame(details['flats'])
```

Secondly, regarding your problem you probably have a problem with your import, try writing at the beginning of your script `import pandas as pd`

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second solution is neater. Thank you.